# Bash script pauses after cat command. I'd like it to run the whole script

Tags: shell-script

I am running a bash script that gets stuck after `cat alphmajors`. Do I have to tell the script to continue after displaying the output? Why does the script pause after that line?

Also, I'm anticipating my current script struggling with `cat >> 2018Students` where normally, I'd add "new student name" and then ctrl+c to exit the command. Can you help my script with that?

```
tar  -xvf University.tar
cd University/Departments/Majors/
sort m2018 > alphmajors
cat alphmajors
mv alphmajors ..
cd ../../Professors
touch NewHires
cd ../Students/Undergraduate/
cat >> 2018Students
cd ../Graduate/
cat GradStudents >> ../Undergraduate/2018Students 
cd ../Undergraduate/
rm -r ../Graduate/
grep "\ S" 2018Students > SNames.txt
cat >> SNames.txt
sed '/myname:/d;1i\myname' SNames.txt
```

Comment: I'd think it would wait at `cat >> SNames.txt`, not `cat alphmajors`

Comment: Yeah... "cat >> SNames.txt" is your problem... cat is waiting for input on stdin since no input is specified before redirecting it's output...

Comment: `cat >> 2018Students` comes first. If you really want user input from the console, best to `echo 1>&2 'Please enter Students data -- Ctrl-D to end.'` just before each such cat command.

Comment: "... and then ctrl+c to exit the command.Ctrl-C". That abandons the command, probably not writing all the data to the file. For each cat from the terminal to a file, you need to enter Ctrl-D -- generates EOF condition on the input stream.